# R: How to control font size of legend map in plotly/ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization

How can I control the font size of the legend map in plotly/ggplotly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the font size of the legend using `legend.text` in your `theme` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=3))

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

```r
p <- iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15))

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>